# Elasticsearch : how to return the document with the exact word searched and not all documents that contain that word in an sentence?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have field (type text) named 'description'

I have 3 documents.

doc1 description = "test"

doc2 description = "test dsc"

doc3 description = "2021 test desc"

CASE 1- if i search "test" i want only doc1

CASE 2- if i search "test dsc" i want only doc2

CASE 3- if i search "2021 test desc" i want only doc3

But now only CASE 3 is working

For example CASE1 not working .If i try this query i have all 3 document

```
GET /myindex/_search
{
    "query": {
        "match" : {
            "Description" : "test"
        }
    }
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting all three documents in your search because by default elasticsearch uses a [standard analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html), for the `text` type field. This will tokenize `"2021 test desc"` into

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "2021",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 4,
      "type": "<NUM>",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "test",
      "start_offset": 5,
      "end_offset": 9,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 1
    },
    {
      "token": "desc",
      "start_offset": 10,
      "end_offset": 14,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

Therefore, it will return all the documents that match any of the above tokens.

---

If you want to search for the exact term you need to update your index mapping.

You can update the mapping, by [indexing the same field in multiple ways i.e by using multi fields.](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html#add-multi-fields-existing-field-ex)

```
PUT /_mapping
{
  "properties": {
    "description": {
      "type": "text",
      "fields": {
        "raw": {
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And then reindex the data again. After this, you will be able to query using the "description" field as of text type and "description.raw" as of keyword type

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "description.raw": "test dsc"
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "67777521",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 0.9808291,
        "_source": {
          "description": "test dsc"
        }
      }
    ]
```